# Qt 5 installation failure

Tags: c++, windows, qt, installation, qt5

Long story short, this is what I get when I try to install Qt 5.4:

[image]

My system is Windows 8.1 x64 and I have plenty of space on all of my drives. What I've tried so far:

- using both offline and online installers
- resetting %TMP%/%TEMP% environment variables (I use tmpfs partition for that)
- running installer as administrator

Comment: Have you tried the 32 bit installer?

Comment: @lpapp yes, unfortunately with the same result.

Comment: Strange, how much space do you have where you are trying to install to?

Comment: @lpapp, 65GB. I hope that's enough:)

Comment: Can you try to select only minimal installation?

Comment: @lpapp when I do that I get the same error with only lesser amount of space needed.

Comment: Have you tried different than msvc2013?

Comment: @lpapp, Didn't help either. I guess it's an OS-related issue, not installer itself.

Comment: Can you install other things?

Comment: Might be related: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTIFW-605?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin:activity-stream-issue-tab

Comment: @lpapp Thank you for your help! But I surrendered and reinstalled windows from scratch and now it works fine:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment discussion, it seems to mean some corruption on your system that may trigger this failure as a reinstall of your Winows 8.1 seems to have made this working.

For future reference: in general, you could debug this issue by trying to install 32 bit verison instead of 64 bit. If that does not work, you could pick up minimal installation. If that does not work, you could try another compiler variant, etc.

Naturally, you always need to make sure that you run this as system administrator, too.

Disclaimer: this fresh issue reported could also be an issue under "extreme" circumstances:

[Segfault when running installscript.qs using "replace"](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTIFW-605?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin:activity-stream-issue-tab)